# cUrl login is not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to one of my sites using curl to pull information off the page.  It does not seem to be working.  Here's the code I'm trying.  If it helps I can create a user/pass for just this scenario.

```
<?php

$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$loginUrl = 'http://gwintersdev.com/user';
$finalUrl = 'http://gwintersdev.com/admin';

$userinput = 'name';
$passwordinput = 'pass';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$userinput=$username&$passwordinput=$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'user-agent');


ob_start();      // prevent any output
curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output

curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $finalUrl);

$buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
print $buf2;
?>
```

Update: I was able to get the above working, but I'm trying this on a different ASP site and it's not working. I grabbed all the hidden fields and added them to the post string, but it still won't login.

```
<?php
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';
$loginUrl = 'http://vitalstim.com/health_professionals/certified_provider_resources/forum.aspx';
$finalUrl = 'http://vitalstim.com/health_professionals/certified_provider_resources/forum.aspx';
$userinput = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uc_login$txtUser';
$passwordinput = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uc_login$txtPass';
$login = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uc_login$butLogin';

$validation_input = '__EVENTVALIDATION';
$validation_input_value = '/wEWAgKf+PTrBQKItpn5BDXHCHsANbEpwkEBmMyNv+32L2Ec';
$view_state = '/wEPDwUJLTQyMjg0NzI0D2QWAmYPZBYGAgEPZBYEAgYPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZAIHDxYCHwBoZAIDD2QWBAIBD2QWCAIBD2QWBAIBDw8WAh4EVGV4dGVkZAIFDw8WAh8AaGRkAgcPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPFgIfAGhkAgkPDxYCHwBoZGQCCw8PFgIfAGhkZAIDDxYCHwBoZAIFDw8WAh8BBXY8c2NyaXB0IGxhbmd1YWdlPSJqYXZhc2NyaXB0IiB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiPgokKGRvY3VtZW50KS5yZWFkeShmdW5jdGlvbigpIHsKVml0YWxTdGltLkluaXQoNCk7Cn0pOwo8L3NjcmlwdD4KZGRkdz/7+FcQ1E1sbC0Gua3jJsCGSnM=';
$event_valid = '/wEWBwKeiM4xAoi2mfkEAurz/r4MAvTX0jYC+4GopQkCo6iimggC2pO41g77y84VwyhP6Ek+7PGZYDNgOawRZw==';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,   "$userinput=$username&$passwordinput=$password&$validation_input=$validation_input_value&$login=login&__EVENTVALIDATION=$event_valid&_VIEWSTATE=$view_state");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'user-agent');
curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $finalUrl);

$buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print $buf2;
?>
```

Comment: Why are you opening and closing and then re-opening the cURL connection?

Comment: So what specific problem are you having?

Comment: what error are you getting? check the log file.

Comment: dont close the curl connection, use the same `$ch`. Are there any other inputs you are missing?.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing two hidden fields that are in the source of that form. CSRF protection kinda. You can try scrapeing that, by doing a third request, before the other two, and getting those values, and putting them in the second request.

Also, like i said in my comment above, dont close your curl handler.

Any more info you can give would be awesome

**EDIT:**

As for the `ASP` page: `asp` is terribly difficult to curl this with. It could easily be hiding fields that you need. My suggestion would be to create a fake page, that `print_r`'s `$_POST` and `$_GET`, and change the action of the form on their page with chrome, or firebug, to submit to your page. Just to check if you are missing anything

I did what i suggested to try, and i got this:

```
Array
(
    [__EVENTTARGET] => 
    [__EVENTARGUMENT] => 
    [__VIEWSTATE] => /wEPDwUJLTQyMjg0NzI0D2QWAmYPZBYGAgEPZBYEAgYPFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZAIHDxYCHwBoZAIDD2QWBAIBD2QWCAIBD2QWBAIBDw8WAh4EVGV4dGVkZAIFDw8WAh8AaGRkAgcPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPFgIfAGhkAgkPDxYCHwBoZGQCCw8PFgIfAGhkZAIDDxYCHwBoZAIFDw8WAh8BBXY8c2NyaXB0IGxhbmd1YWdlPSJqYXZhc2NyaXB0IiB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiPgokKGRvY3VtZW50KS5yZWFkeShmdW5jdGlvbigpIHsKVml0YWxTdGltLkluaXQoNCk7Cn0pOwo8L3NjcmlwdD4KZGRkdz/7+FcQ1E1sbC0Gua3jJsCGSnM=
    [ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uc_login$txtUser] => test
    [ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uc_login$txtPass] => test
    [ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uc_login$butLogin] => Login
    [__EVENTVALIDATION] => /wEWBwKeiM4xAoi2mfkEAurz/r4MAvTX0jYC+4GopQkCo6iimggC2pO41g77y84VwyhP6Ek+7PGZYDNgOawRZw==
)
```

Comment: Awesome. I got that to work for that site once I added in the two hidden fields and stopped closing the connection.  I need this to work on two different sites, and it won't seem to work on the other site though.  Here's the code I'm trying for that. I can't seem to find any other input fields.  Is there anything else that could be causing problems with it?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up doing the trick.
http://www.mishainthecloud.com/2009/12/screen-scraping-aspnet-application-in.html?showComment=1368565341638#c9104469935977149435